# I would like to disable a custom button once after clicking it in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, custom-button, html, template

```
<template> 
  <lightning-button  class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Save as Draft" type="submit" 
   name="Save as Draft" onclick={handleSubmit}>
  </lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

```
handleSubmit() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.qEventErrorOccured = false;
        this.qEventFormSubmitCount = 0;
        this.prevRecordStatus = this.recordStatus;
        this.recordStatus = 'Draft';
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
        this.disableButton = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Boolean values, like disabled, can be set to true or false. When true, they act as if they are present, and when false, act as if they are not.

[Example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/bbeVeXy5Gw3hrwMVEXwc/src/app.js).

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  disabled = false;
  disableButton() {
    this.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-button disabled={disabled} onclick={disableButton} label="Disable me!">
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

See [Boolean Properties](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript#boolean-properties).

Edit: This property does not appear in the documentation, but it does work on lightning-button in both Salesforce and LWC OSS (as from the first link).

Comment: @PhilW Just saw your comment, I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a disabled attribute in your lightning button

`<template>  <lightning-button  class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Save as Draft"  type="submit" name="Save as Draft" disabled={disabled} onclick={handleSubmit}> </lightning-button> </template>`

And your Js should be like

```
disabled = false;
handleSubmit() {
    this.disabled = true;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.qEventErrorOccured = false;
    this.qEventFormSubmitCount = 0;
    this.prevRecordStatus = this.recordStatus;
    this.recordStatus = 'Draft';
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
}
```

Comment: How is this any different to the existing answer?